# set data from server to class's property angular 2

Tags: angular, observable, angular-promise, angular-http

I want to set the data from observable to a property. but it takes time for response to comeback. so the property gets set to `undefined`. How do I set the data from server to the class property

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.comics.getChar().subscribe((responses: Response) => this.data = responses[1].json().data.results);
    this.comicsList = this.data; // gives undefined
    console.log(this.comicsList);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not understanding how asynchronous functions run.

this line:

```
this.comics.getChar().subscribe((responses: Response) => this.data = responses[1].json().data.results);
```

doesn't "finish" before progressing to this line:

```
this.comicsList = this.data; // gives undefined
```

the first line BEGINS executing, and then the next line executes right away regardless of whether the first one finishing.  That's the nature of asynchronous execution, you don't know when it will finish, so everything else that doesn't depend on it just continues executing.  However, in this case, your second line explicitly depends on the response, so you need to set it up so that it runs only AFTER you've gotten your response:

```
this.comics.getChar().subscribe((responses: Response) => {
    this.data = responses[1].json().data.results;
    this.comicsList = this.data;
});
```

This is a little redundant, unless you have a reason to maintain two references to this list, I'd probably just set comicsList directly in the subscribe.

Although I probably wouldn't even do that, I'd do this:

```
this.comicsList$ = this.comics.getChar().map(responses => responses[1].json().data.results);
```

and in my template where I need this data, I'd subscribe with the async pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let comic of comicsList$ | async">{{ comic }}</div>
```